# Full Access Administration mode for lotus notes using C API

Tags: c, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am using `NotesInitIni(char far *pConfigFileName);` function to initialize a notes session. But i want a notes session with full access admin mode enabled. In my machine i am only having Notes Client on my machine ,the Domino Admin client is not installed. When I am googling for full access admin mode in the notes C API I am not able to find anything. When I am searching in all notes C API header files (inside notesapi folder and include folder) I am not able to find any functions for full access admin mode. Does anyone know how to connect to the lotus notes as “full access administration” mode using the notes C API?